# error importing localhost export file to server

Tags: php, database, mysql, localhost

I've built a wordpress site through a WAMP local host server and have exported it onto a single SQL file. I've installed wordpress onto my third party server but when I try to import this file onto the database I get an error.

> SQL query:
>
> --
>
> ### -- Database: `cosmosdesign`
>
> ### -- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
>
> CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
>   `meta_id` bigint( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
>   .`comment_id` bigint( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `meta_key` varchar( 255 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
>   `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
>   ) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = >utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>   1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'

I'm not experienced enough to know what this means, could someone please explain it to me and hopefully suggest how I could fix it? Thankyou.

ps. I won't be able to reply for an hour or so.

Comment: There is a answer for your question in stackoverflow site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916610/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having this issue as your third party server doesn't support the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` collation type.

You can either contact your host to correct this or convert the collation for all tables with `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Thankyou, I did a search and replace for utf8mb4 to replace it with utf8. This fixed this error. Now I'm stuck with a new one. Thanks for the help.